# Looking for *numeric* cpu monitor for (Vista 64) system tray

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, cpu-usage, notification-area

I'm looking for a system-tray based cpu monitor for Vista (and Vista 64) which displays as numeric.  [SpeedswitchXP](http://www.diefer.de/speedswitchxp/) doesn't work in Vista 64.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Vista x64 requires driver signing, not many CPU utilities work properly in it (due to unsigned drivers). There are some workarounds like disabling driver signing system-wide or using "test signing" mode for application's driver. But, disabling driver signing wouldn't be good.

It seems there is only one tool that has signed driver and hence works fine on Vista x64 - CrystalCPUID. Check it out here:
http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalCPUID/index-e.html

It can be run in system tray by using the command line switch */HIDE /CQ*. Check the FAQ section in that website for more info.

Comment: Hi Swatkat thanks for the response.  The key thing I'm looking for though is for the system tray icon to display numeric values rather than a graph or some other representation (e.g. colors in the case of CrystalCPUID tool).

It definitely does seem like there's limited choices in this case.  Thanks again.